# Slug for standard post post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, archives

I have a custom post type with an archive page, e.g.: `example.com/chronicle`.

I want to have a page that lists the standard post type, post. This works: `example.com/?post_type=post`. But, I want to have something like `example.com/posts`.

The front page lists both posts and chronicles.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress offers you the ability to create a custom URL structure for your permalinks and archives.

For this you will have to change permalink, Permalinks allows you to choose your default permalink structure.

To change permalink go to **Settings** > **Permalinks** in WP Backend.

Choose **Post name** In *Common Settings* Section.

Comment: I'd suggest also read here https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks and understand the logic of things